# How is it that we cycle through the nanas?

Tags: practice, visuddhimagga, nana, mahasi

The knowledges(nanas) start at realizing mind and body. After the last knowledge, the practitioner goes back to realizing mind and body again?

Is that correct?

What is the difference between the first time realizing mind and body and the second time realizing mind and body?

Answer (score 1):

The word “gnana” is the very opposite on “Vinnana”. “Gnana” is Wisdom. In cultivating “gnana”, one’s avijja is reduced. Then what  naturally accompanies or follows is the reduction of certain types of vinnana.

A type of gnana that one develops through the understanding of Tilakkhana is “anulöma gnana”.  When one comprehends anicca, dukkha, anatta to the extent that one gets to ‘see’ this Tilakkhana, one is said to have the “anulöma nana”.  This gnana helps in the removal of craving for worldly things to some extent.

A special knowledge that one gains of the workings of Pali language is “patisambidha gnana”. This is the awareness of the Syntax in the Pali language. It is the understanding of the arrangement of words and phrases to create new words. Unlike the English language, the meaning of the Pali word changes, in the way it gets used. A Pali word can have more than one meaning. A Pali word can have a conventional meaning and a deeper meaning. One who gains “patisambidha gnana” sees the deeper meaning of key words.

Another gnana that one could gain is “udayabbaya gnana”. When one develops this gnana, one can see the causes that need to be eliminated to overcome otherwise inevitable future suffering. S/he then learns of the factors relating to all knowledge about the arising and destruction of anything in this world. S/he also gains the knowledge on how to stop anything from arising in this world. This is the ‘nirodha’ aspect of things.

Answer (score 0):

It is called the right knowledge and the right release.
By following the Noble Eightfold Path the practitioner continually gains the knowledge and release on many levels. There are mainly four levels. (Sotapanna etc) But there are many intermediate levels hence it is called gradual training.
Arahant is the final fruit of right knowledge and right release.

Answer (score 0):

**

```
> One thing: you have to walk, and create the way by your walking; you
> will not find a ready-made path. It is not so cheap, to reach to the
> ultimate realization of truth. You will have to create the path by
> walking yourself; the path is not ready-made, lying there and waiting
> for you. It is just like the sky: the birds fly, but they don't leave
> any footprints. You cannot follow them; there are no footprints left
> behind.
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Once got the knowledge of review, there is reflection on realizing mind and body but this time is not the same as one underwent in the very beginning. Clearer and vivid as it is. Once attain enlightenment i.e, got through all 16 stages of nana thoroughly preferably fully guided by the well-learned meditation master how to recognize the changes of nana, next time meditation will begin with knowledge of arising and passing away and then going step by step upward. Please refer to insight meditation practice by mahasi sayadaw.